# Read JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have a JSON result after Ajax as following

```
 {
"results": [

{
    "id": " 14903",
  "nsid" : "10438",
    "name": "001-2501220",
  "label":"001-2501220 End Seal",
  "price":"12.6"
}, 
{
    "id": " 14904",
  "nsid" : "10439",
    "name": "001-2501231",
  "label":"001-2501231 Poppet",
  "price":"12.3"
}, 
{
    "id": " 14917",
  "nsid" : "3391",
    "name": "PW16001",
  "label":"PW16001 Caliper Piston 38.1mm Lucas TRW handbrake",
  "price":"26.5"
} 
]}
```

I am facing difficulties reading this. I have tried as

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          data: "partnumber=" +value,
          cache: false,
          success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            for (var i in data.results) {
                var name = data.results[i].name;
                var text = data.results[i].label;
                console.log(name);
                console.log(text);
            }
          },
          error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
              alert(err.Message);
          }
        });
```

But no luck.

Comment: Show your ajax code and where this code is in relation to that, it matters, a lot.

Comment: i have updated ajax call

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? And what does `console.log(data);` output?

Comment: no errors.. in `console.log(data)`, i am able to get that JSON in console.. but console appear for loop

Comment: I works well for me

Comment: Try adding `dataType: "json",` in your ajax options so the JSON string is properly converted to an object

Comment: This helped.. datatype:json

Comment: Why downvote?? Pl mention reasons as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your server doesn't send proper `application/json` `Content-Type` response header and jQuery doesn't know that it should automatically parse the response before passing it to the `success` callback. So if this is the case you could explicitly indicate the content type when making the request:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

Now assuming that this wrongly written server side script sends valid JSON, jQuery will properly parse it before feeding it to the `success` callback so that you can write the corresponding loop over the results elements.

This being said, I would recommend you fixing your server side script so that it correctly populates the `Content-Type` response. This would allow clients such as `jQuery` to properly handle the response.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your JSON response is returned as `data` and not by any other name. Also since javascript is async you will need to perform this action in the `jquery ajax success()` function. You can also use it outside but that requires some you will need to handle that differently. One more thing add `dataType: "json"` in your ajax code, it will make sure your returned data is valid JSON and you may need to parse it

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          data: "partnumber=" +value,
          cache: false,
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data){

            var data = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(data);
            for (var i in data.results) {
                var name = data.results[i].name;
                var text = data.results[i].label;
                console.log(name);
                console.log(text);
            }
          },
          error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
              alert(err.Message);
          }
        });
```

```js
var data = {
"results": [

{
    "id": " 14903",
  "nsid" : "10438",
    "name": "001-2501220",
  "label":"001-2501220 End Seal",
  "price":"12.6"
}, 
{
    "id": " 14904",
  "nsid" : "10439",
    "name": "001-2501231",
  "label":"001-2501231 Poppet",
  "price":"12.3"
}, 
{
    "id": " 14917",
  "nsid" : "3391",
    "name": "PW16001",
  "label":"PW16001 Caliper Piston 38.1mm Lucas TRW handbrake",
  "price":"26.5"
} 
]}

$.each(data.results, function(key, val) {
console.log(val.name);
           console.log(val.id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: but i have only that json returned as response from server side.. i do not wish to modify Server.. any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: how can i assign `var data` to that response?

Comment: you dont need to assign a variable. You success function will be like `success: function(data) { console.log(data)}`. If yes then you are ok